# Rails: How to persist object errors on redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller

I'm working on a bastardized poorly maintained rails application. I have an update action on rails which for both the successful and unsuccessful update involves a redirect (not render), because the routes are messed up and i can't easily type render 'edit' (which I assume would persist the errors).

Is there a way for me to persist the object errors into a view to display them as errors on the form? Because on the redirect on the view as far as the form is concerned the errors aren't there. It looks something like this:

```
      complex_path = "/path_name/path_2name/edit/#{@product.id}"
      if @product.update(part1_params)
        flash[:notice] = completion_message
        format.html { redirect_to complex_path
 and return }
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Unable to save Product. "
        format.html { redirect_to complex_path and return }
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm it's a bit hacky, but you can use custom keys on the Flash hash.

```
else
  @product.errors.keys.each do |err_key|
    flash[err_key] = @product.errors.full_messages_for(err_key).join(' ')
  end
  flash[:alert] = 'Unable to save Product.'
  redirect_to ....
end
```

Now, for the next request, you can iterate over `flash.keys` to get the errors (you should ignore the :alert o :notice keys).

It's really ugly, but redirecting after `save` failed is uglier so.... ;P